# Why do we use the natural base for the logarithm in the Kullback–Leibler divergence?

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Well known formula of KL divergence when we have a discrete probability distributions.

$$D_{KL}(P \parallel Q)=\sum\limits_i \ln \left(\frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}\right) P(i)$$

Can someone explain why the natural base of the logarithm? That will probably not yield the information in bits as a result?

Do I need to change the base of the logarithm to 2 in order to get the relative entropy in bits?

Or there is another way?

Thank you.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\log_2 x = \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e 2} = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}
$$

Expressing entropy in bits means using base-$2$ logarithms.  Just divide the base-$e$ logarithms by $\ln 2$ and you've got it.

Comment: Thanks Michael,

Can you tell me is this correct way of expressing KLD?

$D_{KL}(P \parallel Q)=\sum\limits_{i} \log _2 (\frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}) P(i)$

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{{{}}}}}}}$